# ¿Cómo hago un debug de un código PHP?

Tags: php, depuración

Cuando mi código tiene un error, el navegador, por ejemplo CHROME, solo me arroja un mensaje por consola indicando un error general. Luego tengo que revisar mi código para saber donde se encuentra el error (generalmente un *;*). Quisiera saber si hay algún programa que ejecute PHP y me devuelva un log de errores. Como por ejemplo; un programa donde compilas el código (visual basic); inclusive el mismo MYSQL, no compila código, pero cuando la consulta está mal escrita te informa de cual es el problema.

Comment: Hay debbugers pero creo que lo mejor es que tu lo hagas. Tienes algún código de ejemplo donde te pasen esos errores?

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo PHP, puedes configurar la visualización de mensajes de error para que te muestre detalles sobre los errores que ocurren en tu código.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

También puedes utilizar herramientas de depuración externas como Xdebug